# How to restore nautilus 20.04 appearance

Tags: appearance

I was playing around `setting`-> `appearance`-> `Window colors` that changed the nautilus appearance to an old version. I was happy with the new look. Is it possible to restore that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the pics from the same system? It seems icon theme some how changed? Did you remember anything that you changed from gnome-tweaks?

Comment: The first one is for me the second I got from a search to show what I mean by new look. I change the appearance from tweak then I restore the change and remove Tweak but I think when I click on the Appearance from system setting it changed the look.

Comment: So you initially had the second image b4 you started playing with the appearence rite. Do you have gnome-tweaks installed??

Comment: Yes I just Installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the file browser looked fine, Then I installed tweak and played with appearance, It did not change the file browser. Now I have removed Tweak and restart to see if it restore back. but it is still the same.

Comment: You should not have removed tweaks.. Reinstall tweaks n change the Icon theme to Yaru. If nautilus is opened close it and open again.

Comment: Yes, it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The things present in your images are:

**Main theme:**

- Ubuntu's default "Yaru" theme

  - you seem to be using the "Yaru Dark" variant
  - you can change between 3 variants: "Light", the default, and "Dark", on the *Appearance* tab of the standard *Settings* app (also called *Gnome Control Center*)

**Icon-sets:**

Those dark-grey/purple-ish folder icons belong to the icon-set used by the "Yaru" theme, also called "Yaru" icon-set. To me, these seem to be optimized for dark themes.

The brighter, orange icon-set is called the "Humanity" icon-set. They were used as the default on previous versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 16.04). I find that they offer a much more readable experience in Nautilus, when using a light theme.

You can change the icon-set used in your theme either by running commands like these in the terminal:

```bsh
# To choose Yaru
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Yaru'

# To choose Humanity
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Humanity'
```

or by installing the `gnome-tweaks` app and changing the "Icons" setting on its *Appearance* tab.